# Can we tell the browser to set a specific header field?

Tags: php, http, web, webserver

Can we tell the web browser to set a specific header? I want the web browser to fetch a token from an authentication site. The browser then should set the acquired token in its header field:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

I know this can be achieved with cookies easily but I am wondering if the server can tell the client to set a specific **header field** for its future requests.

Comment: How do you do that with cookies (easily)?

Comment: No, that is not possible from the server side.

Comment: You can do this in JS on the client side, but as a default for 'normal'/future page requests, I very much doubt it.